# making scipy.special functions evaluate in parrellel

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This seems too simple to be unresolved, I am sure I just am not looking in the right place. This question has bothered me for a while, so here goes...

Can a function like scipy.special.j1 execute on a numpy array using multiple cores?

```
from scipy.special import j1
import numpy as np

tester = np.random.randn(1000,1000)
out = j1(tester)
```

Running a timeit in ipython and watching the system monitor shows only 1 core runs. numpy and scipy are installed through conda, and there are 'mkl_rt' and 'pthread' libraries in scipy.__config__ outputs.

Running np.exp uses 4 avalible cores.

```
out = np.exp(tester)
```

If possible, it would be nice to use all avalible cores for the j1 calculation, but 4 is certainly better than 1. Is this simple somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in pure python.

You can use the Cython interface of `cython_special` in conjunction with `prange` though.